# In javascript, why is my argument in static method undefined in Chrome debugger?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React/javascript helper class like this, but for some reason when I use Chrome debugger, it says `arrOfObj` is undefined, while `hi` works fine. Anyone know the reason why? Would like to learn what javascript nuance I'm missing. Thanks!

```
export default class JSUtil {
  static average(arrOfObj, fn = null) {
    // for some reason JS debugger cant access arrOfObj, but works if I declare a const inside it
    const hi = arrOfObj
    debugger
  }
}
```

```
VM2903:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: arrOfObj is not defined
    at eval (eval at average (JSUtil.js:1), <anonymous>:1:1)
    at Function.average (JSUtil.js?e5fd:55)
    at useDatePriceMap (UseDatePriceMap.js?f60b:40)
    at CityDatePicker (CityDatePicker.js?325d:57)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js?61bb:14803)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js?61bb:17034)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js?61bb:18610)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js?61bb:23179)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?61bb:22154)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js?61bb:22130)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js?61bb:21756)
    at eval (react-dom.development.js?61bb:11089)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js?3069:653)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js?61bb:11039)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js?61bb:11084)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js?61bb:11072)
    at batchedEventUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js?61bb:21877)
    at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js?61bb:795)
    at dispatchEventForLegacyPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js?61bb:3568)
    at attemptToDispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js?61bb:4267)
    at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js?61bb:4189)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js?3069:653)
    at dispatchUserBlockingUpdate (react-dom.development.js?61bb:4172)
```

```
hi
(61) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Comment: This looks like a calling context issue. Show how "eval" is being called. It isn't clear what frame you would be in when debugger is stopped. `arrOfObj` may not be propagated to the frame that the evaluation is being made

Comment: If you are using `eval` it has a funny way of using the variable context. You cannot call a function that calls eval. Even something like `var debugger=eval`, and trying to use that to evaluate local variables will not work